# Disable a button when clicked then enable after refresh

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

I have a button on a page that when clicked runs a sub that populates a gridview with data from an SQL table.  I am using VS2010 with VB.

When a user clicks the submit button I want to disable it instantly and then run the sub and once the sub has ran enable the button again.

I added the below to the button click event but it does not work

```
        imgbtnComDetailGo.enabled = False

    Call Sub()
    imgbtnComDetailGo.enabled = True
```

It does not appear to be disabling the button instantly.

UPDATE - I found this code on google

```
OnClientClick="this.disabled = true" UseSubmitBehavior="true"
```

but it does not appear to call the SUB as nothing happens apart from the button gets disabled.

Comment: Try to use ajax to do that.

Comment: I assume this is ASP.NET?

Comment: ok - I have added the tag. For future questions please tag WinForms/ASP.NET/WPF etc as appropriate as this helps to get the correct answer

Comment: Could you post your button1 click event markup?

Comment: Yes, please show us the signature of the Sub.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a javascript to the button from code behind (eg. Page_Load event):

```
sJavaScript = "this.value='Please wait...';" ' optional button text 
sJavaScript &= "this.disabled = true;"
sJavaScript &= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(imgbtnComDetailGo, "")

imgbtnComDetailGo.OnClientClick = sJavaScript
```

In case your page has validators, wrap the above sJavaScript with additional script before assigning to the button's OnClientClick:

```
sJavaScript = "if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {if (Page_ClientValidate()) {" & sJavaScript & ";}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with some script. here's code:

use this in your utility file and call whenever you need

**C#**

```
public static void SubmitDisable(System.Web.UI.Page source, ref System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button button)
        {
            string script = null;

            script += "if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function')";
            script += "{";
            //script += "   /if client-side does not validate, stop (this supports validation groups)";
            //script += "   //however before validating attempt, must save and, then restore the page validation / submission state, otherwise";
            //script += "   //when the validation fails, it prevents the FIRST autopostback from this/other controls";
            script += " var oldPage_IsValid = Page_IsValid;";
            script += " var oldPage_BlockSubmit = Page_BlockSubmit;";
            script += " if (Page_ClientValidate('" + button.ValidationGroup + "') == false)";
            script += " {";
            script += "     Page_IsValid = oldPage_IsValid;";
            script += "     Page_BlockSubmit = oldPage_BlockSubmit;";
            script += "     return false;";
            script += " }";
            script += "}";

            //script += "//change button text and disable it";
            script += "this.className = 'ButtonPleaseWait';";
            script += "this.value = 'Working ...';";
            script += "this.disabled = true;";

            //script += "//insert the call to the framework JS code that does the postback of the form in the client";
            //script += "//The default code generated by ASP (WebForm_DoPostbackWithOptions) will not ";
            //script += "//submit because the button is disabled (this is new in 2.0)";
            script += source.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(button, null) + ";";

            //script += "//MUST RETURN AFTER THIS, OTHERWISE IF THE BUTTON HAS UseSubmitBehavior=false";
            //script += "//THEN ONE CLICK WILL IN FACT CAUSE 2 SUBMITS, DEFEATING THE WHOLE PURPOSE";
            script += "return true;";

            button.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
        }
```

on page load you just call `Util.SubmitDisable(this,buttonID);`

**CSS :**

```
.ButtonPleaseWait { background: #F3F3F3 url('../images/pleasewait.gif') no-repeat 2px center; border: thin solid #000; width: 100px; height: 25px; color: #333; font-weight: bold; text-indent: 15px; font-size: 1.13em; }
```

**asp.net**

just use `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` in your asp.net button